# rails active admin interface : has_many - select from the model containing has_many, not frm that containing belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have these two models(jst examples to explain u):

### institues.rb

name
type : (like school , college)

rb file :
attr_accessible :name, :type, :user_id
belongs_to :user

### user.rb

name

rb file:
attr_accessible :name
has_many :institutes

From the active admin, I am able to select the user while creating or editing an institue. But, what I want to do is, while editing or creating a user, it should show an option to select as many institues that the user studied in.

Concept :
A single user will study in schools, collegs. While creating the user, we should be able to select all the institues he studied in. Without having the necessity of going to each and every institute he studied to select him .

This is just an example, and in my example, a single institue can accomodate a single user.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested forms for institutes by building the institutes(build 2 institutes) when user gets instantiated. Also use jquery stuff to add more institutes when you run out of institutes.